# URLEncoderでUnhandled exception

Tags: android, java

検索文字をURLエンコードするために`java.net.URLEncoder.encode()`を使ったのですが以下の`Unhandled exception`がでてしまいできません｡  なぜでしょうか｡

**Unhandled exception :**

```
Unhandled exception: java.io.UnsupportedEncodeingException
```

**URLEncoder使用箇所のコード :**

```
if(this.searchWord!=null&&!this.searchWord.equals(""){
  this.searchWord = URLEncoder.encode(this.searchWord, "utf-8");
}
```

Comment: `utf-8` を `UTF-8` という感じで大文字に変更したらどうなりますか?

Comment: 今､試して見ましたが変わりませんでした｡

Comment: Java の文字列は内部では `UTF-16` で保持されていますので、`URLEncoder.encode(this.searchWord.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")` などとする必要があるのかもしれません。実際に確認していませんので、間違っていましたらごめんなさい。

Comment: @haliac2001 様
現在試して見ましたが､直りませんでした｡

Comment: すみません、お手数をお掛けしてしまいました。。。ちなみにですが、`UTF-16` を指定しても(`URLEncoder.encode(this.searchWord, "UTF-16")`)、やはりエラーになるのでしょうか?

Comment: @heliac2001様
いえいえ､コメントいただけるだけでもありがたいです｡
`UTF-16`で指定しても エラーは消えませんでした｡

Comment: 実行環境はなんですかね? 実機? エミュレーター?

Comment: @KoRoN 様
実行環境は実機です。Nexus7を使っています。バージョンは5.0.2です

Comment: 暇人の戯言です。Logcatを仕込んでエンコード前のthis.searchWordが何てモニターに表示されてるか確認していただけますか。

Comment: @user3009331様
次のように表示されました｡
`D/searchWord﹕ てすと`

Comment: 現時点の情報からはまったく理由がわかりません。しかし **URLEncoder使用箇所のコード** について、`if` 文の閉じカッコが足りないように見受けられます。そのことから、コードの転載時になにかしらの誤りを含んでしまい、実際のコードとは異なるものが書かれているのではないか、と推測しています。確認して、必要ならば修正してえいただけないでしょうか。できれば前述のlogcat への出力を含むものが好ましいです。

Comment: すみません｡私のミスで例外処理を忘れていました｡  お騒がせして申し訳ございません。 親切な対応をありがとうございました｡

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unhandled exception というメッセージはコンパイラが出すエラーではないですか？try catchを書いていないのではないでしょうか？

```
try {
  this.searchWord = URLEncoder.encode(this.searchWord, "utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodeingException e) {
}
```

のような感じで書きます。
これはAndroidではなくJavaの文法の話なので、詳しいことは`java 例外`などで検索してみてください。

Comment: Matuo 様 
その通りでした｡ありがとうございます!